# What arguments do exist against defining completeness in NP using injective Karp reductions?

Tags: computational-complexity, open-problems, np

It is crucial to use the *right* notion of reduction to define completeness inside NP. Different notions of completeness inside NP may have significant impact on the properties of complete languages. Initially, P vs NP problem was formulated by Cook using polynomial-time Turing reductions. Later Karp refined the notion of completeness using polynomial-time many-one reductions. It is not known whether complete problems are equivalent under different notions of completeness ( Cook vs Karp reductions).

[This post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32373/completeness-under-injective-karp-reductions) on CS Theory shows that defining completeness using injective Karp reductions would prove $P \ne NP$. The reason is that SAT is dense language and can not be reduced to a sparse language using injective Karp reductions. Mahaney's Theorem states that $P=NP$ if and only if there is a Karp reduction from SAT to a sparse language.

Also, one of the answers highlights the fact that all known Karp reductions to NP-complete problems are injective. There is no known natural NP-complete problem via Karp reduction that can not be made one-to-one. If Cook had defined NP-completeness using injective Karp reductions then the P vs NP problem could not existed.

> What arguments do exist against defining completeness in NP using injective Karp reductions?

Proving the existence (or non-existence) of polynomial-time algorithms for SAT would be more satisfactory way to resolve P vs NP but it is important to link it to the existence (or non-existence) of incomplete languages inside NP. [Ladner's theorem](https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=YnLmsHAtvYEC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=ladner+cryptocomplexity+nor&source=bl&ots=s-gtQ19RgC&sig=fsC_yU0ddFjzYlrHyzcC4xdxQiU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ladner%20cryptocomplexity%20nor&f=false) states the $P\ne NP$ if and only if there exists an incomplete language in $NP$ \ $P$ (under Karp reductions).

Comment: Isn't the title of this question a little misleading? The question that is really being asked is your second one: "What arguments do exist against defining completeness in NP using injective Karp reductions?"

Comment: @Abel edited the post to address your concern.

Answer (score 13):

If, for some (mysterious) reason, injective reductions were taken as the standard, then, even if we couldn't reduce SAT to certain PTime problems by such restricted reductions, that wouldn't tell us that SAT can't be solved in PTime.

In other words, the fact that any PTime solvable problem can be reduced to any other (nontrivial) PTime solvable problem is no longer available if we impose strange restrictions, like injectivity, on the reductions.  As a result, reducibility of SAT to other problems would no longer serve as a criterion for whether P=NP.

EDIT after discussion in comments: I think I now see your main error, namely the hypothesis, quoted from one of your comments, "if all Karp reductions between NP-complete problems are in fact injective." This hypothesis is false. For example, there is a Karp reduction of SAT to SAT that sends each instance $x$ to itself, except that, if $x$ is just a propositional variable, then its sends $x$ to the first propositional variable $v_1$. This is a many-one Karp reduction between NP-complete problems, but it is not injective.

One could consider a weaker and not obviously false hypothesis, namely that whenever there is a Karp reduction from one NP-complete problem X to another NP-complete problem Y then there also exists an injective Karp reduction from X to Y.  This weaker hypothesis trivially implies P$\neq$NP, without any need for anything as complicated as sparse sets (and in fact without knowing about SAT).

Proof: Assume this weaker hypothesis, and assume, toward a contradiction, that P=NP. Then the PTime computable sets $\{0\}$ (where $0$ denotes the empty string) and its complement $C$ are both NP-complete, in the usual sense of many-one Karp reductions. In particular, each is many-to-one Karp reducible to the other (by a function taking only two distinct values).  But there is no injective Karp reduction of $C$ to $\{0\}$; every Karp reduction must send all elements of $C$ to $0$ and would therefore be very far from injective.

Comment: Do you observe that $P \ne NP$ if and only if there is an incomplete language (other than $\Sigma^*$ and $\phi$) in NP (under Karp reductions) ?

Comment: Mahaney's Theorem states that $P=NP$ if and only if there is a Karp reduction from SAT to a sparse language.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany Does any of this work with injective Karp reductions?

Comment: Ladner's theorem states the $P \ne NP$ if and only if there exists an incomplete language in $NP$ (under Karp reductions). Also with your logic we can argue against Cook reductions since the non existence of Karp reduction between two problems (from A to B ) does not imply the non existence of Cook reduction (i.e. A is not PTime reducible to B via Cook reduction ).

Comment: I don't see how your latest comment is relevant to my answer.  What, exactly, would you argue against Cook reductions?  The crucial point is that $P\neq NP$ is equivalent to "there is no Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P" and also equivalent to "there is no Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P", but I see  no reason to believe that it is also equivalent to "there is no injective Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P."

Comment: I have not claimed an equivalence between Karp and Cook reductions. I claimed an equivalence between two specific statements concerning these sorts of reductions, namely "there is no Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P" and "there is no Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P." The equivalence that I claimed is correct, even though Cook reductions are more general than Karp reductions.

Comment: What is your proof to the claim:  "there is no Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P" implies "there is no Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P." ?

Comment: Both statements are easily equivalent to "SAT is not in P."

Comment: Ok. Give me your proof.

Comment: (1) Any problem that is reducible (in Karp's or Cook's sense) to a problem in P is also in P. (2) If a problem X is in P, then it is Karp-reducible (and therefore also Cook-reducible) to any nontrivial problem Y. By non-trivial, I mean that Y has at least one positive instance, say p, and at least one negative instance, say q. Then the Karp-reduction needed for (2) is the PTime function that sends all positive instances of X to p and all negative instances to q.  (If you have any more questions about basic complexity theory, please see a textbook.)

Comment: You only proved that "there is Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P" implies "there is Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P." But you did not prove your claim:  "there is no Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P" implies "there is no Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P."

Comment: I gave all the ingredients for the proof that you claim is lacking; all that is still needed is some trivial logic: If there is no Karp reduction of SAT to your favorite nontrivial problem in P, then, by (2) from my previous comment, SAT is not in P, and then by (1) there is no Cook reduction of SAT to your favorite problem in P.

Comment: The problem in your statement (2) is that your are using a weak reduction (Karp). But if you use Cook reduction then your proof fails. Your are using Karp and Cook reductions as if they are interchangeable but they are not. Cook reduction is stronger.

Comment: Please read my comments more carefully, so as not to make any more absurd statements about what I wrote. My statement (2) says that, under certain conditions, there is a Karp reduction, and it notes, in parenthesis, that this implies the existence of a Cook reduction. I said nothing about "interchangeable" but only that, when there is a Karp reduction then there is also a Cook reduction.

Comment: But that does not prove that "there is a Cook reduction then there is also a Karp reduction" which is equivalent to  "there is no Karp reduction then there is also no Cook reduction" .  That is my objection.

Comment: Of course it doesn't prove that "if there is a Cook reduction then there is also a Karp reduction". That's probably false in general.  So what? That implication is neither needed nor used in my comments. Why do  you want it? All that is needed or used is the easy fact that "if there is a Cook reduction of a problem X to a nontrivial problem Y in P then there is also a Karp reduction of X to Y". That special case is true, and I proved it in previous comments.

Comment: Go back to my comments. I simply asked for a proof that "there is no Karp reduction then there is also no Cook reduction"

Comment: Your last comment is ambiguous. If you want a proof that "if there is no Karp reduction from X to Y then there is no Cook reduction" for arbitrary X and Y, then you won't get such a proof, because, in that generality, the statement is false. If you want a proof for the special case where Y is a nontrivial problem in P, the case that is relevant here, then I already gave the proof.

Comment: Also in my post I restricted reductions to Karp reductions.

Comment: Right. Cook reductions entered this thread only in your third comment. If you now claim they're irrelevant, then I agree. They are not mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Dear Andreas, my post is about incompleteness under restricted version of Karp reduction. So I am free to consider your answer as unsatisfactory.

Comment: My answer is about the same restricted version of Karp reduction, namely requiring the reducing function to be injective. You are, of course, free to consider it as unsatisfactory, since you apparently don't understand it.  I assume that you are the person who downvoted it; I would hope that other readers can understand it.

Comment: Finally, I down voted since your first paragraph in your answer is false. The reason is that SAT can not be reduced to nontrivial Ptime sparse set via injective Karp reduction (hence P≠NP by Mahaney's theorem and assuming all Karp reductions between NP-complete problems are in fact injective). Exponentially dense set like SAT can not be reduced to sparse set via injective Karp reductions. Please read the link to the post on CS Theory. It seems you did not read it .

Comment: A better argument: all known NP-complete problems are exponentially dense. If all Karp reductions between NP-complete problems are in fact injective then the first paragraph in your answer is false (Since SAT can not be reduced to sparse set (in $NP$ \ $P$) via injective Karp reductions). Such sparse language is incomplete and by Ladner's theorem $P \ne NP$ would follow.

Comment: In your third paragraph, reducing SAT to itself is highly artificial. I am referring to the hypothesis "if all Karp reductions between _natural_ NP-complete problems can be made injective". This is clear from the linked CS Theory post. I was lazy in expressing the point in the comment .

Comment: Your answer is contradictory. The old part before the edit argues against injective Karp reductions while the part after the edit argues for it. Please clarify your answer. BTW, what you concluded in the second part was already proven on the linked CS Theory post: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32373/completeness-under-injective-karp-reductions

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany (1) The only one arguing in favor of injective Karp resolutions here is you.  (2) It's not at all surprising that what I wrote can be found elsewhere; most of it is obvious. The only reason I wrote it here is that you failed to understand it and kept raising unjustified objections.

Comment: Oops. I guess your are the only one who does not understand the significance of injective Karp reduction and its role in the Isomorphism Conjecture!. Agrawal and Watanabe state in their abstract that "it has been widely believed that all NP-complete sets are reducible to each other by one-to-one length-increasing polynomial-time reductions ".  As for the proof on CS Theory SE, you ignored it and insisted on coming up with your own even though my post was asking for known arguments against injective Karp reductions. http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2009/019/

Comment: (1) I'm not at all surprised by the claim about "widely believed" that you quoted. I pointed out, though, that this widely believed claim trivially implies P$\neq$NP. There's nothing surprising there either, since P$\neq$NP has also been widely believed. (2) It's sometimes easier, and quite common in informal discussions, to just point out a trivial proof rather than citing someone else.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for having the patience to carry this lengthy discussion.